# How to programmatically zip/download google drive folder?

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

You can recursively download a folder, but you eventually run into rate limits with this method of downloading a folder.

Some people online have mentioned AppScript's being a potential solution, but with no real solutions provided.

Today, does google provide a robust method for downloading larger folders? Ideally, a method to zip on their end, then download -- so you avoid the rate-limits of trying to individually download each file.

Comment: This is out of scope for the google drive api.